# scrolling to the far end of the page

Tags: javascript

How can I scroll to the far right of the page. The width of the page varies. So, I don't know the width of the page before?

I tried using `window.scrollTo`, but it is not working as I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. I found that `scrollIntoView` method works best.

Docs on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollIntoView)

Answer (score 0):

**Quick and dirty solution** (and hope that no IE version will not hang up on this):

```
window.scrollTo(100000, 0)
```

**Correct Solution** (measure width of content and page and scroll to specific point):

Include [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and do it like this:

```
var innerWidth = $(window).width(),  // = browser width
    pageWidth = $(document).width(); // = 2010 (div + border)

window.scroll(pageWidth - innerWidth, 0);
```

See the ​[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcgrabow/qgWRg/) here.

Answer (score 0):

Since width will vary, you will need to get the width of the document after the page has been rendered, then once you have that value, you scroll to it.  Here's an example:

```
<script>
  var width = document.body.offsetWidth;
  window.scrollTo(width, 0);
</script>
```